# JAVA Stack Pop Error, trying to create an undo

Tags: java, netbeans, stack

I am try to do an `undo button` using `stack` so that it would remove the effect applied such as `blur` etc , but when i try to `pop out` the `image` i stored in the `stack` something goes wrong , please help me , thanks in advance!.

Applying effect:

```
if (e.getSource() == btnGrayscale) {
  if (buffImage != null) {
    Imagesteps.push(buffImage);
    ImageEffects ie = new GrayscaleEffect();

    buffImage = ie.GrayscaleEffect(buffImage);
    Icon icon = new ImageIcon(buffImage);
    lblImage.setIcon(icon);
    statusBar.setText("Image is now Grayscaled");
  }
}
```

UNDO method:

```
if (e.getSource() == undoimageitem) {
  BufferedImage temp = (BufferedImage) Imagesteps.pop();
  Icon icon = new ImageIcon(temp);
  lblImage.setIcon(icon);
  statusBar.setText("Undo");
}
```

Comment: Given the two conditions, are you sure you are actually putting the Image within the stack in the first place?

Comment: yes, iam sure the push is working fine , but when i   `BufferedImage temp = (BufferedImage)Imagesteps.pop()` Error occurs

Comment: If that is the case then you should post the stacktrace, or whatever you are getting and expecting. *something goes wrong* isn't exactly the best way to describe a problem.

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.EmptyStackException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the exception you are getting it seems that you are trying to pop from an empty stack. To avoid this error you should ideally, before popping, make sure that the size of the stack is at least greater or equal to 1.

As to why you are getting the exception, the reasons could be many. Two that come to mind are these:

- You are re-initialzing/clearing the stack at some point in your code between pushing items and popping them from the stack.
- Assuming that, like most buttons, the method is activated by one click, you are double clicking the button, thus causing the event to fire twice, which could lead into the code performing two pop operations which is causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks @npinti i was re-initialzing the stack in another method thx very much!

Comment: @xArd: Glad this helped. Whenever someone answers your question, it is usually a good idea to mark their answer (by clicking on the green *very good* mark under the answer score). This will show on your stats when you ask a question and will encourage other people to answer your questions.